# How to retrieve time from mySQL to compare in PHP 7?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I want to insert time into MySQL and retrieve it then compare with current time.

Despite of the fact, a plenty of questions regarding to this topic, after hours of searching, most of them answered with mySQL Queries only or how to format timestamp. It is really hard to find out for my case. but I guess my problem differs. I cannot even start with the retrieved datum.

The idea is that when a data posted, it checks the `last_update_time` in DB with `country_code`. If `last_update_time` is within an hour, it just retrieve the time and other data. and If the the time difference is over an hour, it updates the row in DB.

The server is located on a remote site so the timezones are different.And using php 7 and mySQL 5.7

The inserting time into DB in a timezone specified works well, the last_updated_time field type is `DATETIME` in MySQL.

```
function insertData($countryCode) {
  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASSWORD, DBNAME);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

  date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Seoul'); 
  $currentTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

  $sql = "INSERT INTO my_table (country_code, last_updated_time)
                              VALUES ('$countryCode', '$currentTime')";

  if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "INSERT Succeeded";
  }else {
    echo "Failed INSERT";
  }

 $conn->close();
}
```

and later I need to compare the old time(saved time) with current time when a page refreshes. I expect people from several timezones so I set `date_default_timezone_set()`.

```
function compareTime($countryCode){
  $conn = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASSWORD, DBNAME);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

  $sql = "SELECT last_updated_time FROM my_table WHERE country_code = '$countryCode'";
  $savedTime = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  if($savedTime->num_rows == 0) {
       echo 'does not exist';
  } else {

      date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Seoul'); 
      $currentTime =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
      $oldtime = strtotime($savedTime);
      $timeDiffInSec = intval(strtotime($currentTime) - $oldtime) % 60;

      $formattedOldTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$oldtime);
      echo '<p>Current Time: '.$currentTime.'</p>';
      echo '<p>Old Time: '.$formattedOldTime.'</p>';
      echo '<p>Time Difference: '.$timeDiffInSec.'</p>';

      // Do the job only after 1 hour
      if ($timeDiffInSec > 60 && $currentTime > $oldtime) {
        // Do the job and update DB
      }
  }
  $conn->close();
}

compareTime('us');
```

The problem I have is that I don't know how to properly get the saved time from mySQL in PHP. I cannot print the old time on the webpage or compare those two time.

Although the saved time looks like `2017-12-26 17:07:37` when I see via myPhpAdmin, those `echo`s print like below.

```
Current Time: 2018-01-01 06:35:55
Old Time: 1970-01-01 09:00:00
Time Difference: 55
```

Even `echo $savedTime;` prints nothing. How can I resolve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to do $oldtime = $savedTime->fetch_assoc(

Comment: Side note: This isn't exclusive to php 7.

Comment: Btw, why aren't you using a prepared statement for this? You realize that you're leaving yourself open to an serious sql injection, right? That is if you plan on going or are live with this.

Comment: Tank you both of you and thank you for mentioning sql injection.

Comment: @KyleKIM you're welcome. Now, seeing that you appear to be learning in working with databases, there are manuals you can consult if you haven't already and here are a few taken from the official php.net website 1) How to query a db http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php 2) Error checking http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error-list.php 3) error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php (and) 4) prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php 5) *Enjoy the ride!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$savedTime is a query result, you should fetch the results later on.

Try this:

```
$oldtime = strtotime(mysqli_fetch_array($savedTime)[0]);
```

By the way, as Funk Forty Niner reminded me on the comments, you should consider to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to avoid SQL injection attacks. Have a look on the link, it's worth it.

Comment: I see that was my problem. I thought it gets the field value in raw. I have been learning DB for weeks. thank you, sir.

Comment: IMHO, there should have been a mention about the sql injection. Seeing they're learning, we wouldn't want them to end up with a deleted or compromised database.

Comment: Yes, sure, I try to always explain this but this time I didn't. I update the answer now. Thank you very much for the reminder.